# How to prevent generating the ID attribute in TwitterBootstrapMVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In TwitterBootstrapMVC, the razor snippet

```
@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
```

generates HTML like:

```
<input class="form-control" id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="">
```

This will cause the generated HTML to be INVALID if the same property name is used in two controls. For example, if a page includes two partial views, each for a model type which has an "UserName" property.

I tried `Id(null)` and `Id(String.Empty)` but the Id attribute is still generated.

Is there a way to prevent generating the ID attribute at all? like:

```
<input class="form-control" name="UserName" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: While you right to be concerned about the `id` attribute, you should also consider that this will also create the same `name` attribute so how will it post back correctly?

Comment: Suppose I have multiple forms in a page, the scope of `name` is a form while `Id` is the entire page.

Comment: Should be OK then. Can you use `@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "SomeUniqueID" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your help. But what I want is to generate html tag have NO `Id` attribute at all.

Comment: For that you are going to have to write your own helper, but whats wrong with have ID's if they are unique?

Comment: Inspired by your code, I finally got a solution : `TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountName).HtmlAttributes(new {id = (String)null})` , thanks @StephenMuecke

Comment: The generated ID won't be unique if I have multiple instance of the same partialView in one page.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I find a solution for TextBox: `TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName).HtmlAttributes(new { id = (String)null })` <br/> But failed for CheckBox .

Comment: Cool. (hadn't realized that `MergeAttributes` would ignore null values). But in terms of making them unique, you could pass a value to the partial using ViewDataDictionary that could be used as prefix or suffix when generating the ID's - but if you don't need the ID's, stick with your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from @StephenMuecke, the solution is:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountName).HtmlAttributes(new {id = (String)null})
```

But TwitterBootstrapMVC also generates client validation and other tags that requires a non-null `Id`, for example, the checkbox cannot be hacked using `null` `Id` as TwitterBootstrapMVC generates associated Label. An exception will be thrown for

```
@Html.Bootstrap().CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe).HtmlAttributes(new {id = (String)null})
```

So the only option to avoid Id conflict I can think of is prefix the Id to make it unique in entire page when **creating multiple instances of the same partial views inside a container page (such as an `AccountList` page that have multiple partial view `MemberInfo_Partial` instance, each for an account)**, which also be mentioned by @StephenMuecke. The TextBox in partial view `~/Views/Account/MemberInfo_Partial.cshtml`:

```
@f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountName).Id(this.UniqueId(m => m.AccountName))
```

will have `Id` as `Account-MemberInfo_Partial-AccountName` for the first occurs in the containing page, and `Account-MemberInfo_Partial-2-AccountName` for the second occurs, and so on.

The code for `UniqueId` is here: https://gist.github.com/Yaojian/2605701c4885c2629002